# I am not able to logout from facebook in android(Facebook sdk is 3.21)

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am not able to logout from facebook in android. Facebook sdk is 3.21

```
 public void logoutFromFacebook() {

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    // User successfully Logged out
                    Log.d("Dilip Logout successfully", "");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {

            }


        });
}
```

**Logcat Error is**

> Logout from Facebook: {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid application ID. (101)","request_args":[{"key":"format","value":"json"},{"key":"method","value":"auth.expireSession"}]}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975266/facebook-error-application-id-is-invalid you created new object of facebook which is not authorized.. so make facebook object singleton

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323449/how-to-logout-using-facebook-api-in-android

Comment: please refer this link. it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-log-out-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-log

Answer (score 3):

### Your logcat returns

> Invalid application ID.

You can use **Facebook SDK 4** . Read Officials Document **[LoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout)**

> Session is used to authenticate a user and manage the user's session
>   with Facebook.
>   Sessions must be opened before they can be used to make a Request.
>   When a Session is created, it attempts to initialize itself from a
>   TokenCachingStrategy. Closing the session can optionally clear this
>   cache. The Session lifecycle uses SessionState to indicate its state.
>   Once a Session has been closed, it can't be re-opened; a new Session
>   must be created.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```